# How do I enable md5 authentication for only one user?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, logins, pg-hba.conf

I just installed Postgres 9.2 on CentOS 7. I want to keep peer authentication for all my users except one, which I would like to be able to access via "psql" through any user's account. I tried editing my /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf to be this

```
local   all             all                                     ident
local   all             scale                                   md5
```

but I'm still unable to login with the user "scale" unless I'm in that user's account. What do I need to do to set up md5 authentication for this one user only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pg_hba.conf` looks only for the first match. Try switching the order..

```
local   all             scale              md5
local   all             all                ident
```

You'll have to reload the conf

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Or, using something like

```
service postresql reload
```